# Ionic - HTTP POST request not working on native Android but working on Ionic Devapp

Tags: android, cordova, http, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to make a post request using the ionic native HTTP module in my ionic app. When I run the app using Ionic DevApp, the request works and the app works fine. When I use `ionic cordova run android --device` to build and run the app natively on my device, the http request is failing.

I've been trying a bunch of options listed in other stack overflow questions. I've installed `cordova-plugin-whitelist` and modified my config.xml to include all different types of access orgin and allow navigations. I also made sure my Android Manifest has:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

I'm at a loss for what else I can try and I figured this is not a CORS issue with the API since the request is working perfectly when I use `ionic serve -c` to run it through the Ionic DevApp.

Just for reference, my API request looks like:

```
 var headers = {}
 this.http.setDataSerializer('json')
 return this.http.post(API_URL, send_data, {headers: headers})
  .then(data => {
 ...
 }
```

In my `config.xml` file I've included:

```
<access origin="*" />
<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="localhost:8080" />
<allow-navigation href="data:*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="localhost:8080" />
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, this has been a huge time drain and the frustrating thing is the app is fully functional and succesfully making the http post request from the Ionic DevApp. Thanks.

Comment: if you are using this [plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/) it will not run in the browser but it will run on your ionic dev app

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean? I'm not interested in running it in my browser I want to run it as a native android app

Comment: are you using this [plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/) in your app?

Comment: I am using that plugin

Comment: can you try your app using ionic devapp, it should work i just recently use the plugin

Comment: Yes, as I stated in my question my app works perfectly on Ionic DevApp but it's failing when I run it as a native android app. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: you are using emulator right? correct me if im wrong . if you are using emulator i dont know why it occurs I didnt try to use emulator because i have something problem about my android studio im too lazy to fix it lol, but if you try to build apk it should work on your android phone

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183338/discussion-between-ritwik-biswas-and-nyx97).

Comment: @RitwikBiswas Are you referring localhost in API_URL by any chance? Could be a CORS issue as well

Comment: @Nicolas Are you referring localhost in API_URL by any chance? Could be a CORS issue as well

Comment: how does `API_URL` looks like?

Comment: Hi, this is not my question. However my problem is very similar. In my case, i'm accessing my API via the ip address of my computer  + the port link to the docker who is running my API. Ex : 192.168.0.126:8080

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried connecting the chrome debugger to see why your post request fails?
You can do this by going to chrome://inspect 
You should be able to see your app there (assuming your phone is connected and in dev mode).
Once you see your app, click inspect. This should open a chrome debugger window allowing you to see the network traffic.

Please reply with the result.

Comment: I have, the request goes on for about a minutes an then timeout. I get a `POST http://192.168.0.126:8080/index.php/Login net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` message in the console.

Comment: Did you try reaching this url from i.e. the browser on the phone? It seems to me like the url is not reachable from the network/ip your phone is on. This would match with your issue since the dev app runs through the pc while the run is fully on the phone. 
Check your hosting settings/portforwarding/firewall etc...
It might even be the case that you need to use your external ip (if i.e. you are using 4g)

Comment: Wow, i have not tried that. And turns out the IP i was using changed. This was my problem, I feel so dumb right now. You sir, deserve some reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing resource/android/xml/network_security_config.xml

With,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain>api.mydomain.in</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```